# Mimicking a bluetooth disconnection

Tags: connection, bluetooth

I've written a program to control a bluetooth device. I'm trying to test cases when the bluetooth disconnects, i.e. if its out of range.

Physically taking the device out of range is one possibility, but its quite cumbersome and I have to go outside my office to achieve this.

What can I do to trigger a disconnection? Is there, for example, an interferer I can setup, say with an Android phone, that would make the connection drop? Or limit the Bluetooth transmit power? Any other possibilities?

Comment: This completely depends on the bluetooth devices you are using. What are they?

Comment: The bluetooth device is a custom device we built, based on the RN-42 chip.

Comment: What is the other device in your scenario? If you're using an Android phone, manually disconnecting (through the program) is one possibility. You can also turn bluetooth off (on the phone) while the devices are connected to simulate an abrupt disconnection.